# How to get the line numbers for all matches?

Tags: vimscript

How can I get the line numbers of all matching strings in a buffer?
Like in this buffer, I want to get the list `[1,6,50]` of all line numbers with matching strings.

```
1:  test ....


6:  test ....

50: test ....
```

Comment: Welcome to our site :) I suspect that you are facing a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/288754): what do you actually want to do with this list once you get it? Because there is possibly an easier way to do it than parsing the line number and then reusing these numbers. For example using this command `:execute 'grep test ' . expand('%') | copen` would get the lines matching your pattern in the quicklist window which is pretty useful. (The limitation being that you need your buffer to be saved in a file)

Comment: @statox, over the years I had quite a few cases where I needed to obtain the indices of the elements that match a predicate. Unfortunately Vim doesn't offer any simple solution.

Comment: Something like `let mylist = [] | g/^test/call add(mylist, line('.'))` should work okay. But @statox is right: 9 out of 10 it's XY problem.

Comment: @LucHermitte I don't doubt there are some use cases for this exact feature but as you said there is no simple solution, that's why I asked the final goal to see if there wouldn't be a simpler solution for OP. I do like your first solution chaining `map`, `filter` and `map` tho that's smart :)

Comment: @Matt this is also worth an answer :+1:

Comment: @Matt @statox . thanks for comment,  I want to auto generate  comments for go func or method, so i must get all lines that math the `func Xxx ` or `func () Xxx`, i had write regex, but i need to get these lines. so i asked this question.

Comment: Still don't see what's problem with just `:g`. Internally it does two passes and works just okay. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing two manual passes over the text is rarely needed. Most often one just does

```
g/^test/DoSomething
```

And that's enough. The reason is that `:g` is implemented in two passes, so it's not a problem if you, say, add a few lines after each match.

However, if you really want those numbers in a List, you can achieve this with the same pattern:

```
let temp = []
g/^test/call add(temp, line('.'))
```

Comment: Thanks. i got it work.

Answer (score 2):

A convoluted (and untested) way I sometimes use. The idea is to use `map()` to associate line numbers to the actual (matching) lines, then `filter()` to keep only the matching lines, then `map()` again to return only the line numbers

```
" Note: This code uses lambdas and vim 8.{recent} methods.
:echo getline(1, '$')->map({l, v -> [l+1, v =~ 'test']})->filter({k,v -> v[1]})->map({k,v -> v[0]})
```

Another convoluted approach consists in using a function that permits to apply changes as matches are found <del>(still untested)</del>

```
:let g:lines = []
:call getline(1, '$')->map({k,v -> v =~ 'test' ? add(g:lines, k+1) : g:lines})
:echo g:lines

" or 
:call map(getline(1, '$'), {k,v -> v =~ 'test' ? add(g:lines, k+1) : g:lines})
```

Note: we could also use `:global` which is much simpler (see Matt's answer) but as it messes search register and cursor position, I usually avoid it when writing plugins.

Comment: I tried the second on neovim.  i got `trailing characters`

Comment: @xiaodonghuan Vim and Neovim are not 100% compatible. You should add the appropriate tag.

Comment: @xiaodonghuan, I've fixed the second approach, and added the _old_ _method-less_ syntax.

Comment: Note that the way lambda functions are used in Vim9 is slightly changed.